# How to get a group starting at the specified id

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get a group of kol_name starting with the id that gets the ending when the 'status' = 'start' with it included.
It`s mean, I gets 'id' from outside and wants to get a group of columns from the 'start' inclusive, to the next 'start' without him , or last ' add' , the result is used in a dynamic SQL

```
id      kol_name      status
------------------------------
44     kol_name_1      add
43     kol_name_2      add
42     kol_name_3      add  
41     kol_name_4     start 
40     kol_name_5      add
39     kol_name_6     start 
37     kol_name_7     start
```

My expected output is when i get id 44

```
kol_name
--------------------
kol_name_1      
kol_name_2      
kol_name_3       
kol_name_4
```

My expected output is when i get id 37

```
kol_name
--------------------   
kol_name_7
```

My expected output is when i get id 39

```
kol_name
--------------------   
kol_name_5 
kol_name_6
```

how can I do that?

Comment: To do this, you need some way to order your transactions. Is it always by descending id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  One way is to calculate the first start "after" the given id ("after" seems to be a smaller id, which is why I put it in quotes).  Then, you can just use simple logic:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select max(id) as startid
      from t
      where id <= 44 and status = 'start'
     ) tt
where t.id <= 44 and t.id >= tt.startid;
```

If you only wanted to mention "44" once in the query:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select theid, max(id) as startid
      from t cross join (select 44 as theid from dual)
      where id <= theid and status = 'start'
     ) tt
where t.id <= tt.theid and t.id >= tt.startid;
```

EDIT:

This code only returns one row:

```
with t as (
    select 44 as id, 'kol_name_1' as kol_name, 'add' as status from dual union all
    select 43, 'kol_name_2', 'add' from dual union all
    select 42, 'kol_name_3', 'add' from dual union all
    select 41, 'kol_name_4', 'start' from dual union all
    select 40, 'kol_name_5', 'add' from dual union all
    select 39, 'kol_name_6', 'start' from dual union all
    select 37, 'kol_name_7', 'start' from dual 
   )
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select max(id) as startid
      from t
      where id <= 39 and status = 'start'
     ) tt
where t.id <= 39 and t.id >= tt.startid;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/12845) is a SQL Fiddle

EDIT II;

Oh, you want *two* rows with 39.  If that is the case, change the definition of `startid` using no equality:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select max(id) as startid
      from t
      where id < 44 and status = 'start'
     ) tt
where t.id <= 44 and t.id >= tt.startid;
```

Comment: thanks ,I tested the script for the various possibilities and if there is a possibility that when I have id = 39 i get the result = kol_name_5 , kol_name_6

Comment: @AdamNowak . . . SQL Fiddle correctly returns one row in this case.

Comment: sorry I did not specify the exact question I mean it gets 'id' from outside and wants to get a group of columns from the 'start' inclusive, to the next 'start' without him , or last ' add' , the result is used in a dynamic SQL

Comment: @AdamNowak . . . I believe this answers the question that you asked.  If you have a *different* question, then ask it as another question.  If you change this question, you will invalidate this answer, which is rude because that draws downvotes.

Comment: The question is still the same your response is very good just does not work for example, for the 39 , and the third proposed sql not work in my case , my table has more than 1000 lines , I'm sorry if I was rude before .

Comment: I tested your script before ' EDIT II ' for id 39 gives me two lines that are ' off ' for groups or two other groups , the test kol_name_6 , kol_name_7 , the expected result kol_name_5 , kol_name_6.